# Initials LDAP Attribute in Claim Rules for Microsoft Active Directory Federation Server

Tags: adfs, federated-identity

Does anyone know when setting up claim rules in MS ADFS whether the Microsoft Active Directory LDAP attribute of 'initials' can be selected from the 'Mapping of LDAP attributes to outgoing claim type'. If it's not available as a default option from the drop down list can a custom rule be setup to use the 'initials' attribute for mapping ?
I need this attribute specifically as it stores the username required by an application.
Appreciate any help
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The drop-down is actually editable so type away!

Refer : [ADFS : Selecting claim that's not in the default drop down](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2011/09/adfs-selecting-claim-thats-not-in.html) .